# Sharepoint 2016 Durable link with d string is not found in Internet explorer

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-id, durable-links

In SP2016, for an office doc durable link has no d value in IE. it is fine with chrome. document id feature is enabled in site collection.

Steps:

1. On IE11, for a word document, clicked on the ellipsis.
2. On the preview window, the link is displayed as https://webapp/sitecol/mydoc.doc

But in Chrome, the link displays as https://webapp/sitecol/mydoc.doc?d=w9sf34b253cb243406aa604f9d32da65b5 (expected)

Any Ideas why d string is not appended in Internet explorer?

Thanks

Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Per my test I could't reproduce your issue.

The durable link works well both in IE and Chrome browser.

Please try as following to check the result:

1. Clear IE browser cache.
2. Update to the latest IE version.
3. Open the site in inprivate window to compare the result.

Comment: I tried clearing cache with IE 11 and Edge, both not working. In-private window option is not available (may be policy)

Comment: I found most complain on chrome browser, but not on IE. for me otherway around.

Comment: Could you open the file in IE browser excellently? It seems that the OOS doesn't work properly in IE.